# How to convert number of days to hours using python date format string and strptime function?

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I'm working with dates retrieved from a mongoDB however, **they are not all in the same format**. They come in 3 different formats:

```
1. '%H:%M:%S' (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)
2. '%H:%M:%S.f' (Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds)
3. Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds
```

I want to calculate the total time for all records from the database. The dates are stored in string format so I'm using the strptime function to retrieve a time object, then make a timedelta using that time object so i can add it all up:

```
formats = ('%H:%M:%S', '%%H:%M:%S.f', <3rd format here>)
for db_item in db_collection:
    for fmt in formats:
       try:
           temp = datetime.strptime(db_item, fmt)
           temp = datetime.timedelta(hours=temp.hour, 
                                     minutes=temp.minute, 
                                     seconds=temp.minute,
                                     milliseconds=(temp.microsecond / 1000)
           return temp
       except ValueError as e:
```

Problem however is that the 3rd format I mentioned earlier specifies the n days before the '.', so I have no idea how to write a date format string for this format.

**example**

```
1.01:20:40.97
```

means: 1 day (24 hours) , 1 Hour, 20 Minutes, 40 Seconds and 97 milliseconds

what I'm aiming for:
25:20:40.97 (24 hours + 1 hour)

Is there a format that allows for this? or should I extract the n days seperatly, multiply by 24 and add manually later on?

Comment: the function `datetime.timedelta()` can't give `25:20:40.97`, only `1day,  01:20:40.970000` is possible .

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `%d` format code. However you would run in to limitations as `%d` is the day of the month, meaning it is an integer within range(1, 31+1).
datetime.datetime is specialized in dates and times rather then duration's.

It is probably easier to parse the string using regex and construct the timedelta directly then to use the `%d` format code.

Here is a regex that would work for all 3 of your duration formats.

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(
    """
    # 0? to remove leading zero
    # days and milliseconds are optional
    (?: (\d+). )?   # days
    0? (\d+):       # hours
    0? (\d+):       # minutes
    0? (\d+)        # seconds
    (?: . (\d+))?   # milliseconds
    """,
    re.VERBOSE
)

match = pattern.fullmatch("01:20:40")
if match is not None:  # if fullmatch fails match is None
    print(match.groups())

match = pattern.fullmatch("01:20:40.97")
if match is not None:
    print(match.groups())

match = pattern.fullmatch("1.01:20:40.97")
if match is not None:
    print(match.groups())
```

output

```py
(None, '1', '20', '40', None)
(None, '1', '20', '40', '97')
('1', '1', '20', '40', '97')
```